# How to install imgcat on iTerm2?

Tags: bash

## Question

What do I do with the script? Please explain in plain English in step-by-step fashion.

### Background

I saw that you can display images inline in iTerm2

[image]

But when I clicked on the link to [Download imgcat here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gnachman/iTerm2/master/tests/imgcat) it just took me to a url that had the script. But what do i do with it? copy somewhere? run it after?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Just install "Shell Integration" and it will be automatically installed for you.

On the iTerm2 Menu, just click "Install Shell Integration"

[image]

You should then see the output indicating that imgcat is installed:

```
$curl -L https://iterm2.com/misc/install_shell_integration_and_utilities.sh | bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  2694  100  2694    0     0   2890      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2890
Downloading script from https://iterm2.com/misc/bash_startup.in and saving it to /Users/allan/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash...
Checking if /Users/allan/.bash_profile contains iterm2_shell_integration...
Downloading imgcat...
Downloading it2dl...
Adding aliases...
Done.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The next time you log in, shell integration will be enabled.

You will also have these commands:
imgcat filename
  Displays the image inline.
it2dl filename
  Downloads the specified file, saving it in your Downloads folder.
```

Comment: perfect. thank you for adding the screenshots to make it easy to follow along to.

Comment: Wierdly, fails silently on my High Sierra